How to Login and Register in the same page in laravel?
I'm new to Laravel and I've only did one project where the registration had a .blade file and login had another .blade file.
now I'm working on a project where there's only one .blade file that has 2 forms a normal username password form (login) and some js that makes the registration form appear when i click on a button so I'm having a hard time with making data appear on my database and with the routing and stuff cause there's no /login and /registration routes cause its just 1 page.
i didn't really try much cause i don't understand much but i made the login and registration functions return the same view which is the login.blade file and i gave the registration and registrations functions /register routes and the login and loginPost functions /login routes but now the registration form does not respond to the data inserted doesn't even do anything not refresh no clearing the data entered no nothing.
.blade code
    <form action="{{ route('register_post') }}" method="POST" id="form" class="sign-up-form">
            @csrf
          <h2 class="title">Sign Up</h2>
          <div class="input-field">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
            <div class="error"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <div class="error"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field">
            <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <div class="error"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field">
            <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
            <input id="confirmPassword" type="password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="confirm Password" />
            <div class="error"></div>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn solid 
        </form>

web.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;

Route::get('/login', [AuthController::Class,'login'])->name('login');
Route::get('/register', [AuthController::Class,'register'])->name('register');
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::Class,'loginPost'])->name('login_post');
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::Class,'registrationPost'])->name('register_post');
Route::get('/logout', [AuthController::Class,'logout'])->name('logout');

authcontroller
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    function login(){
        return view('login');
    }
    function register(){
        return view('login');
    }
    function loginPost(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required',   
            'password' => 'required']
        );

        $credentials = $request->only('username','password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)){
            return redirect()->intended(route('home'));
        }  
        return redirect(route('login'))->with('error','Failed to login');
    }

    function registrationPost(request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required',   
            'confirmPassword' => 'required',   
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',   
            'password' => 'required']);

        $data['username'] = $request -> username;
        $data['email'] = $request -> email;
        $data['password'] = Hash::make($request -> password);
        $data['confirmPassword'] = $request -> confirmPassword;
        $user = User::create($data);

        if(!$user){
            return redirect(route('register_post'))->with('error','Failed to Register');
        }

        return redirect(route('login'))->with('success','Youve been registered successfully');

    function logout(){
        Session::flush();
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect(route('login'));
    };
}

}

sorry if its too much

you are going to have to provide some more information and code here .... what does "registration form does not response to the data inserted" mean?

as in like when i enter the credentials and press the form's submit button nothing really happens

You need to include some code in your question, otherwise we can't work out what is going on. Please read the help section on How to Ask and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. We'll need to see your blade file, theweb.php route file, and the controller code to start with. I have a feeling the problem might be in the JS of the blade file if you  are not seeing any data sent to the server.

"i didn't really try much cause i don't understand much" - we all start somewhere, you should start with some tutorials, docs, guides etc.  It sounds like you should be checking your browser devtools to see what the JS is doing, what network requests are happening, etc.

@AbdalrahmanEhab I've just formatted the code and noticed a closing brace } is missing at the end of the registrationPost function. Is this also missing in your project, or was it a mistake when pasting the code here?

@Tony yes its written in the project codes

You can dynamically set the form submission route based on the current endpoint. Here's an example:
 <form action="{{ request()->is('register') ? route('register_post') : route('login_post') }}" method="POST" id="form" class="sign-up-form">


You can try with same route
In web.php
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;

Route::get('/register', [AuthController::Class,'register'])->name('register');
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::Class,'registrationPost'])->name('register_post');
Route::get('/logout', [AuthController::Class,'logout'])->name('logout');

In Authcontroller
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    
    function register(){
        return view('login');
    }

  function registrationPost(request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required',   
        'confirmPassword' => 'required',   
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',   
        'password' => 'required']);

$check = User::where('username', $request->username)->check();

if($check){ 

$credentials = $request->only('username','password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)){
    return redirect()->intended(route('home'));
        }  
    return redirect(route('register'))->with('error','Failed to login');
}

    
$data['username'] = $request -> username;
$data['email'] = $request -> email;
$data['password'] = Hash::make($request -> password);
$data['confirmPassword'] = $request -> confirmPassword;
$user = User::create($data);    
if(!$user){
    return redirect(route('register_post'))->with('error','Failed to Register');
}
return redirect(route('register'))->with('success','Youve been registered successfully');

function logout(){
    Session::flush();
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect(route('register'));
};
}

}

